# How to create a login mechanism with ASP.NET and client side application

Tags: c#, asp.net, objective-c

I'm in the process of designing an iPhone app and I need to create a login mechanism written in ASP.NET on the server. Any ideas how the best way to go about doing this would be?

We would need to be able to create a username/ pass, login, then send a (small) amount of information back and forth from user application to server.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the more "packaged" (I guess is a good word) parts of ASP.NET, but it sounds like you would do great w/ the provided ASP.NET login controls:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx

This gets you pretty far for free (metaphorically) and if you need more later, the MembershipProvider support is pretty rock solid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by iPhone app you are referring to a native (Objective-C) application.  If this is the case then I would probably look at creating a web service ([WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324)) to interact with the server rather than a web site.  The service would allow you to use the native widgets without having to scrape (or manipulate) a DOM object to perform a post back.

Note that there's no reason why a well written web service couldn't also be exposed as a web site if the software follows good design principles.  As @Rikon mentioned the MembershipProvider support provides a good quick out of the box experience although it's easy to out grow what it provides.